# Finding a parsing API for partially utf8 encoded URL's

Tags: c#, .net, uri

When parsing HTML for certain web pages (most notably, any windows live page) I encounter a lot of URL’s in the following format.

http\x3a\x2f\x2fjs.wlxrs.com\x2fjt6xQREgnzkhGufPqwcJjg\x2fempty.htm

These appear to be partially UTF8 escaped strings (\x2f = /, \x3a=:, etc …).  Is there a .Net API that can be used to transform these strings into a System.Uri?  Seems easy enough to parse but I’m trying to avoid building a new wheel today.

Comment: FYI  . please notice that pasting this url as string in browser console  will provide the correct output. ( not realted but FYI)   http://i.stack.imgur.com/2md5D.jpg

Comment: and here is the online tool to play with it...http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you posted is not valid HTTP. As such, of course `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` won't work. But irrespective of that, you can turn this back into normal text like this:

```
string input = @"http\x3a\x2f\x2fjs.wlxrs.com\x2fjt6xQREgnzkhGufPqwcJjg\x2fempty.htm";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\\x([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])",
    m => ((char) int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
```

But notice that this assumes that the encoding is Latin-1 rather than UTF-8. The input you provided is inconclusive in that respect. If you need UTF-8 to work, you need a slightly longer route; you'll have to convert the string to bytes and replace the escape sequences with the relevant bytes in the process (probably needs a while loop), and then use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` on the resulting byte array.

Comment: What do you mean _UTF-8 to work_ ? he has a string which is unicode  by default. can you explain? (p.s. +1)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: His example only includes ASCII characters. It is unclear how he expects non-ASCII characters to be encoded, let’s say `á`. If it’s encoded as `\xe1`, then it’s Latin-1 (not Unicode). If it’s encoded as `\xc3\xa1`, then it’s UTF-8, which means several bytes are used to encode a single character. Since his encoding appears to assume two hex digits after the `\x`, it can’t be using UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Comment: if I write in console `\xe1`  , Does it represent a unicode char or a utf8 encoding ? how does js handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution : (as continued from @timwi solution)

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\\x([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])",
            m => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value, 16)).ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx)?